# Why the red error screen is showing first and then the fetched value come on the screen? Where is the problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to make flutter web application. But the problem is there whenever I refresh the page or come on the screen the first time the error is showing and then after some time the retrieving value comes on the screen and error is gone.

The following:

> NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
>   _StreamBuilderBaseState>#6203e):
>   'documents'
>   method not found
>   Receiver: null
>   Arguments: []

I want to know why this type of behaviour is happening on the page? Where is the problem?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fulltext_search/study.dart';
import 'package:fulltext_search/study_search.dart';
import 'package:fulltext_search/visitor.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(StudentSearchData());
}

class StudentSearchData extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var queryResultSet = [];
  var tempSearchStore = [];

  initiateSearch(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) {
      setState(() {
        queryResultSet = [];
        tempSearchStore = [];
      });
    }

    var capitalizedValue = value.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);
    var lowerValue = value.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + value.substring(1);

    if (queryResultSet.length == 0 && value.length == 1) {
      SearchService().searchByName(value).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
          queryResultSet.add(docs.documents[i].data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      tempSearchStore = [];
      queryResultSet.forEach((element) {
        if (element['fname'].startsWith(capitalizedValue)) {
          setState(() {
            tempSearchStore.add(element);
          });
        }
        if (element['fname'].startsWith(lowerValue)) {
          setState(() {
            tempSearchStore.add(element);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    /*24 is for notification bar on Android*/
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight-24)/3;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text('Student data search'),
          actions: <Widget>[

            FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Student()),);
              },
              child: Text("Student",),
            ),

            FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Visitor()),);
              },
              child: Text("Visitor",),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.grey[400],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white,width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              textColor: Colors.black87,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("History",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

            ),
            FlatButton(

              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VisitorHistory()),);
              },
              child: Text("Logout",),
            ),

          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) {
                initiateSearch(val);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: IconButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    iconSize: 20.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                  hintText: 'Search by name',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          GridView.count(
              childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                return buildResultCard(element);
              }).toList())
        ]));
  }
}

Widget buildResultCard(data) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue,width: 2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                width:120,
                    child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Image.network(data['image'], width:120,height: 120,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                      Spacer(),
                    ]),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(width: 10),

                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Name:- ${data['fname']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,color: Colors.black),),
                        Text('Year:- ${data['year']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,color: Colors.black),),
                        Text('Contact no:- ${data['contact']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,color: Colors.black),),
                        Text('Vehicle no:- ${data['vehicleno']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,color: Colors.black),),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text('purpose of visiting:- ${data['purpose']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,),),
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                        Text('Entry-time:- ${data['Entry-time']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,),),
                        Text('Exit-time:- ${data['Exit-time']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image][image]

Comment: I think in this part of the code:

`for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {`

`docs` is being returned as null, log it to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Add if else statement to return the widget if data is not null, and return a loading ui if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to come from this block of code:

```
  SearchService().searchByName(value).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
      queryResultSet.add(docs.documents[i].data);
    }
  });
```

Your call to `searchByName(value)` seems to resolve with a `docs` that's `null`, which then leads to `docs.documents` to throw the error you get.

It's impossible to say why `searchByName` is returning `null` without seeing the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

try checking for the snapshot data first using `(snapshot.hasData)`, and then return a `Circular Progress Indicator` if the snapshot is empty. This would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because initially, the snapshot does not have any data. You can check whether data has arrived to snapshot by certain conditions.

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
  return MainWidget();
}else if(snapshot.hasData){
  return Text("Error in loading data”);
}else{
  return SizedBox(
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
    ),
  );
}
```